# Mock data for client calling to spring web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, restful-architecture, spring-web

I need to get mock data for client calling to spring restful web services. I know unit testing purpose we can use mock. but my case is not the testing.

Comment: 1. if not for testing, why would you need a mock
2. what have you got so far?

Comment: I need to integrate with existing production web service. so before call it i need to response sample data to client side developer for testing purpose.

Comment: what's stopping you from returning hardcoded data?

Comment: I can hard code but when i integrate with production , there are hard coded data which is unclear the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use hard coded data, or external data file, or external data source to store mock data. I understand the need to host a service that responds but may not be fully wired, to allow early integration with downstream clients. These are the techniques I use, each have pros and cons.

Hard coded data - as you say, is not intuitive or easy to change. Okay for temporary state.

External data file - able to update dynamically as needed

External data source - able to create multiple scenarios with dynamic mock payloads, and change on demand